# How to get Time Differences of Two Dates like x days y hours z seconds t minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using plsql and I need to get time differences of two dates like x days y hours z seconds and t minutes. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [datetime arithmetic matrix](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) difference of two `date` values is a `number`, which is the number of days. As a pure number it has no time components. So it should be converted to the `interval day to second` with [`numtodsinterval`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NUMTODSINTERVAL.html#GUID-5A7392A8-7976-4465-8839-A65EFF1A80B6) function:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     sysdate as dt1,
>     trunc(sysdate) as dt2
>   from dual
> )
> select
>   numtodsinterval(dt1 - dt2, 'DAY') as interval_
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> | INTERVAL_                     |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | +000000000 22:38:59.000000000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5bfd48fd8e9b6faa31e1a6ce5bdc0798)*

But if you have timestamp, then according to the same matrix the difference will be interval by default:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     sysdate as dt1,
>     trunc(sysdate) as dt2
>   from dual
> )
> select
>   numtodsinterval(dt1 - dt2, 'DAY') as interval_
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> | INTERVAL_                     |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | +000000000 22:38:59.000000000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5bfd48fd8e9b6faa31e1a6ce5bdc0798)*

Note that interval has no format in `to_char` function, so to retrieve hours, minutes, seconds you will need to use `extract` function

Comment: You can also explicitly set the data type to an interval in the subtraction of dates using `(dt1 - dt2) DAY TO SECOND` rather than using `NUMTODSINTERVAL`.

Answer (score 1):

The `EXTRACT` function can be used to get a datetime field from an interval value expression (which is what the difference between 2 timestamps returns).

```
WITH my_two_timestamps (ts1, ts2) AS
(
  SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP( '2021-05-08 12:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi' ), 
    TO_TIMESTAMP( '2022-06-21 20:22', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi' )
   FROM DUAL
), ts_diff(diff) AS
(
  SELECT ts2 - ts1 FROM my_two_timestamps
)
  select  extract( day from diff ) days,
          extract( hour from diff ) hours,
          extract( minute from diff ) minutes,
          extract( second from diff ) seconds,
          ROUND(extract( second from diff )) + extract( minute from diff )*60 + extract( hour from diff )*60*60 + extract( day from diff )*60*60*24 total_seconds
     from ts_diff;
```

Comment: What if I have two dates in a table's two columns? Please help.

Comment: My cte has 2 columns. Please update your question with a reproducible example if you want more detail.

Comment: The other answer shows how to get an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND type value from two dates. You could subtract your two date columns and use numtodsinterval as it does. Then to extract the days, hours, minutes, seconds you can use the extract syntax from this answer.